# How to completely disable keyboard on phone gap app

Tags: android, html, xml, cordova, adobe

I have on screen keyboard and want to disable the android keyboard completely this is my config.xml file my Android app source code can be found in 
    https://github.com/bb19500/mathquiz/ thanks a lot. I tried to do something but don't know how to do it

```
<!-- Customize your app and platform with the preference element. -->
<preference name="orientation"                value="default" />        <!-- all: default means both landscape and portrait are enabled -->
<preference name="target-device"              value="universal" />      <!-- all: possible values handset, tablet, or universal -->
<preference name="fullscreen"                 value="true" />           <!-- all: hides the status bar at the top of the screen -->

<preference name="disable-cursor"             value="false" />          <!-- blackberry: prevents a mouse-icon/cursor from being displayed on the app -->
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion"      value="14" />              <!-- android: MIN SDK version supported on the target device. MAX version is blank by default. -->
<preference name="android-installLocation"    value="auto" />           <!-- android: app install location. 'auto' will choose. 'internalOnly' is device memory. 'preferExternal' is SDCard. -->
<preference name="HideKeyboardFormAccessoryBar" value="true"/>
   <!-- Plugins -->

<!-- Core plugins -->
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.battery-status" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media-capture" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.console" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.contacts" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-motion" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.device-orientation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.file-transfer" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.globalization" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.media" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.network-information" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen" />
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.vibration" />
```

Answer (score -2):

i found a solution, i did disable all the text boxes and therefore there is no-were where to write :)